# SystemException in an async Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

Here is the code:

```
protected static async Task httpPost(String url, String data) 
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient()) 
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseURL);
        AuthenticationManager.SetHeadersForCommunication(client);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        String result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        } 
        else 
        {
            throw new SystemException(
                "Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.StatusCode
                + "\nReason:" + result.ToString()
                );
        }
    }  


}
```

When response.IsSuccessStatusCode is true, I get the result on the Console, that is OK.
But when it's not, no exception are handled and the method stay something like freeze.

Comment: How are you calling this code?

Comment: Task result = BaseManager.httpPost(BaseManager.baseURL + "/" + msg.getType() + "/messages/send", json)

Comment: Show us the entire method which calls `httpPost`. Preferably edit it in the question

Answer (score 0):

You are throwing the exception in an async method but probably not handling it correctly. Try following this pattern:

```
Task myWork = null;
try 
{
   myWork = httpPost(url, data);
   await myWork; 
}
catch(SystemException e)
{
   //now you can get at the exception in myWork.Exception
}
```

The collection will store any nested exceptions due to nested async calls. See the documentation for the [Exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.exception(v=vs.110).aspx) property, which returns the aggregate exception.